# Comparing only DATE from database and DATE NOW

Tags: mysql, select

I want to compare two dates one coming from my database with `date(NOW())`.

Am I doing it right?

```
SELECT * FROM owners_info WHERE u_id = 123 AND date(expiration) >= date(NOW());
```

Comment: "Am I doing it right" Does it work?

Comment: Why don't you use [CURDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)?

Comment: @AndyG Yes it works.

Comment: Also `expiration` should already be `DATE`  datatype so you can skip the conversion.

Comment: what is the 'expiration' type ?

Comment: So to your question. Yes, that query do what you expect. Just could use the few optimization we mention.